# Header image not loading in localhost:3000 rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, assets, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on a website using rails. I am trying to create a header with a background image that is separate from the navigation bar. However , when I go to the page in localhost:3000, the image is not loading:
[K&D Welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgOUK.png)

I have added my image to app/assets/images/ and tried the following code in my view:

```
    <header>
        <div class="header-background">
            <%= image_tag("/assets/kiss.jpg")%>
            <h1> 
                Katie & Dan 
            </h1>
        </div>
    </header>
```

And this in my welcome.scss file:

```
.header-background {
    background-image: url("/assets/kiss.jpg")
    width 500px;
    height: 300px;
    order: 2;
}
```

I have tried several suggestions that I have found online, such as changing settings in the development.rb file, using `<image_src= />` instead of `image_tag`,moving my image to the public/assets/images directory. I'm stuck as to how I can get this image to show up in my local environment .

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: Can you share your `config/initializers/assets.rb` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try
`<%= image_tag("kiss.jpg")%>` instead of `<%= image_tag("/assets/kiss.jpg")%>`

Please refer:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: getting: The asset "kiss.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline.

Comment: using  ``` <%= image_tag("/kiss.jpg")%> ``` gives me no error but the image still doesn't load

Comment: I have tried in my local with rails 6, it works fine, may be you are missing something

Comment: Image may be there, please inspect in the browser inspect and may be issue related to scss file.  Missing `;` in the background-img line

Comment: from the inspect, it seems there is a route missing for /kiss.jpg but when I try and make one, it says it doesn't exist

Comment: This should work. @Belle how is your asset pipeline configured? E.g. at `initializers/assets.rb` .

Answer (score -1):

I think you should put your images in the `public/` folder, storing them in another folder named `images/` (for example : `public/images/kiss.jpg`)

Then, you can find your image like this :

```html
<img src="/images/kiss.jpg">
```

Comment: I think you messed up and put the image in the wrong place. It's weird that it doesn't work.